# Cuda + OpenGL : How to display elements of an array

Tags: arrays, opengl, cuda

Lets say that an array of data

```
int data[256][256][256];
```

contains values of 0 and 1.
This data will be copied to device memory (flattened) and processed by cuda kernel changing some values from 0 to 1 and vice versa.
How can i display the data in such a way so

```
if data[x]][y][z]==1
{
//a point of size 1 will be displayed in (x,y,z) coords
}
```

without having to copy that array back to host memory. I want to do it directly from device(gpu) memory.
A simple example would be very helpfull.

Comment: CUDA's SDK example of [volumeRender](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#graphics) might be helpful to see how OpenGL and Cuda work together with 3D volume objects.
Because displaying it is not so simple, you have to use the OpenGL pipeline and an example would actually be an OpenGL tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

The first approach that comes to mind would be to first use a simple *stream compaction* technique, eliminating all 0 values from the stream. Since you already have your data in a comceptually boolean format, this amounts to a *scan/prefix-sum* of those values, so that afterwards each array element stores the number of its preceding elements. Then you use these computed offsets to relocate the array elements into a new buffer (effectively storing all 1-items consecutively), but instead of just copying the (now irrelevant) offset, you store the 3D position (easily computable from the old array index).

What you then have is a simple list of 3D points in a buffer, that you can easily draw with OpenGL, without any copy to host. If you write the final number of 1-points (a by-product of the scan) into an additional buffer you can even use *indirect rendering* and don't even need to query the number of points from the host and thus can just draw the whole thing without *any* readback.

These are just some general thoughts on how this might work, feel free to google for individual keywords if you don't know what I'm talking about. And if you don't know how to draw anything with OpenGL, you will need to get acquainted with OpenGL or Direct3D first, before you can draw anything from GPU (CUDA won't do it for you).

---

**EDIT:** Well, there is a way to draw this whole thing in CUDA. If it's really just a bunch of points and you don't need any sophisiticated rasterization, you can simply transform those points from 3D to 2D like OpenGL does, too (OpenGL isn't magic either, just a bunch of CUDA kernels with some small bits of dedicated hardware in between). So you have a thread for each data item and if this item is `1`, you just transform the point's 3D coordinate (as given by the thread ID) using the usual modelview and projection transformations on homogeneous 4D coordinates (but don't forget to do the perspective divide and viewport transform yourself, because now there's no fixed-function hardware to do that for you). And use this final 2D coordinate to just set a single pixel in an output image.

Of course this won't let you profit (not that easily or straight-forward at least) from OpenGL's other sophisticated things, like rasterization and what not effects you could think about. But it avoids the stream compaction step and you could at least render those points on top of an already existing OpenGL-rendered image (containing the rest of your visualization scene, like a coordinate system or text or whatever), maybe even using your own depth test implementation.

---

**EDIT:** Another way to avoid the stream compaction would be to draw the whole buffer of `0`s and `1`s directly with OpenGL, using the geometry shader to do the coordinate computation and `0`-removal. So what you do is draw all points, using the whole integer array to feed a single `int` attribute and put it through the following shaders. First a simple pass-thru vertex shader:

```
layout(location=0) in int flag;    //single integer attribute
out int vFlag;                     //just passed through

void main()
{
    vFlag = flag;        //GS does the real work
}
```

The geometry shader decides if the point is valid (has a value of `1`) and if yes emits an actual point for it (if not just does nothing, i.e. no point rendered), computing its 3D coordinate from the primitive ID, which is effectively the array index, since we're just drawing points:

```
layout(points) in;
layout(points,max_vertices=1) out;

uniform mat4 modelViewProj;

in int vFlag[];

void main()
{
    if(vFlag[0] == 1)
    {
        vec3 position = simpleIndexMagic(gl_PrimitiveID);
        gl_Position = modelViewProj * vec4(position, 1.0);
        EmitVertex();
    }
}
```

The fragment shader is then just a usual one. Of course those shaders can be customized like you see fit. But the general approach is clear, draw the integer values directly, transforming the array index into a point for only the values that are `1` in the geometry shader. But in how far this gives an improvement over a previous stream compaction needs to be evaluated.

Comment: I am still trying to understand what does the above mean. The fact is i am not very familliar with opengl or cuda. The way i used to draw vertices in opengl was `code 
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
if (volume[p,q,r]==1)         
glVertex3f(p, q, r);
glEnd();`
I want something like that,so it can be called in a cuda kernel.

Comment: @PhilipXenos *"I want something like that,so it can be called in a cuda kernel."* - That won't be possible. A CUDA kernel cannot invoke OpenGL operations. But I suggest you to read a good tutorial or book on *modern* OpenGL first before trying to understand this answer, because you're using CUDA hardware but OpenGL functions from 15 years ago. If you don't know anything about buffer objects or shaders or how modern GPUs are used, there won't be much help for you really. As *George* already wrote in his comment, providing an OpenGL tutorial is not purpose of this answer.

Comment: @PhilipXenos If you're not that familiar with CUDA and OpenGL, the first approach would probably be the best option. First you may look [here](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html) for some introduction to prefix sums and stream compaction with CUDA. Then look [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object) and [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html) for some introduction to vertex buffer objects. All you then need are some CUDA-OpenGL interoperability functions to use the compacted CUDA buffer directly as OpenGL vertex buffer for drawing the points.